# Filtering close values within multidimensional arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

The code down below compares array `a` to the other arrays `b,c,d`. The `comparison` function is supposed to show the indexes where `other` arrays are within `a`. Both the first column and the second columns must be equivalent for it to return a `True` output. For example if `a` has `[0,123.5]` and `b` has `[1,123]` then it would return `False` since the first column values are not equal to be `0,1` but if `c` is `0` as well then it would be `True`. If values are within both of the compared arrays like `[1,123]` is within both `a` and `b` and it is the `5`th index within `a` and the `4`th index within `b` but since the indexes are recorded for `a` the output would be `5`. I am trying to place `math.isclose(a, other, rel_tol= 0.5)` function to them so if the values of the second column are at most differ by `0.5` they would still return `True`, so even though there is a difference between `[0,123.5]` and `[0,123]`, `math.isclose(123.5, 123, rel_tol= 0.5)` has a difference of `0.5` it still returns `True`. How could I get the expected output?

```
import numpy as np 
import math

a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
c = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,121]])
d = np.array([[0,40],[1,55],[0,24],[0,123],[0,4]])
e = np.array([[1,40.2],[1,55]])

def comp(a, other):
    
    try: 
        nrows, ncols = a.shape
        dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
               'formats':ncols * [a.dtype]}

        C = np.intersect1d(a.view(dtype), other.view(dtype))

        # This last bit is optional if you're okay with "C" being a structured array...
        C = C.view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
        print("\n",C)
    except:
        print("No difference")

comp(a, b)
comp(a, c)
comp(a, d)
comp(a, e)
```

Expected Output:

```
[[  0  55]
 [  0 123]]

[[0,55]]

[[  0 123]]

[[ 1 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) for this purpose.

I.e.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[0,12],[1,40],[0,55],[1,23],[0,123.5],[1,4]])
>>> b = np.array([[0,3],[1,10],[0,55],[1,34],[1,122],[0,123]])
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> for i in a:
...     for j in b:
...         if np.allclose(i, j, atol=0.5):
...             print(i, j)
... 
[ 0. 55.] [ 0 55]
[  0.  123.5] [  0 123]
```

You will need to set the `atol` parameter appropriately, so that your definition of "close" is met.